# Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job. Why am I seeing this failure?

Tags: jenkins

[Jenkins Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AFd8.png)

For no reason at all, an error suddenly started to fly out, although before that, the job was launched without problems. What could be the error? I saw articles including here, but I did not understand what the problem was. Please help

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, not everyone will interpret "WTF" as "Why This Fail"?

Comment: This usually happens when running the job with a non existing branch - most often because it was deleted and someone rebuilds the job, or someone manually entered the wrong branch.

Answer (score 1):

In the new versions of the git, the main branch is not the master, but main, and this should be changed on Jenkins. This solved my problem.

Comment: Wow, hadn't heard about this politically correct change!